# ListFragment updating issues

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment with a custom Layout inside of a ViewPager. This ListFragment and the custom layout performs a ListView and a Button which calls an AsyncTask.

After work is done, this AsyncTask calls in onPostExecute the refresh method (created inside ListFragment) in order to update the adapter (code below).
When I press this button **everything works fine until an orientation change occurs**.

Then If I press the button, the list is updated but **no rows are added or deleted**. So i.e if I only have one row and after updating the adapter is empty, no changes are appreciated on List. On the other hand, If some rows should be added to list we only notice that the existing row has changed its content.

If after this "failed" update an orientation change happens, the list is shown fine. So we can say that **the list only updates well the adapter's content after orientation change**.

A reference to main activity is always passed to ListFragment and **the adapter is updated properly** (I checked it whit Logs).

Anyone has any idea? I will appreciate so much.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/Refresh" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Update" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

And code:

```
    public class ResFragment extends ListFragment {
    View view = null;
    public static AdapterRes adapter; 

    public static ArrayList<NodeP> mItems = new ArrayList<NodeP>();
    public static MyAppActivity ref ;   


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new AdapterRes(ref, ref.result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result,null);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

        Button refresh = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Refresh);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ref.initDownloadTask();             
            }
        });

        return view; 
    }

    public void refresh(){ 
        mItems.clear();
        adapter = new AdapterRes(ref, ref.result);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class AdapterRes extends ArrayAdapter<NodeP> {

      Activity context = ref;
      AdapterRes(Activity context, List<NodeP> objects) {
          super(context, R.layout.row_res, objects); 
          this.context = ref;   
      }

      @Override
      public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
      {
          View item = convertView; 
          final ViewHolder holder;

          if(item == null)                                    
          {                                                  
              LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();            
              item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_res, null);

              holder =  new ViewHolder();   

              holder.local = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.local);
              holder.resPartido = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.res);
              holder.foreign = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.foreign);

              item.setTag(holder); 
          }
          else                                        
          {                         
              holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag(); 
          }
          holder.local.setText(ref.result.get(position).local);   
          holder.res.setText(ref.result.get(position).res);
          holder.foreign.setText(ref.result.get(position).foreign);
          return(item); 
      }

      public class ViewHolder {
          public TextView local;
          public TextView res;
          public TextView foreign;
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: whats the code of your adapter?